# Angular Hiding Navigation Arrows

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-directive, ng-bootstrap

I need to hide the navigation arrows in my carousel on the following condition:
First you need to hide the prev navigation arrow when you are on the first slide and 
Last you need to hide the forward navigation arrow when you are on the last slide.
It is already working now. My problem is when i combine the videos and images. How can i hide the prev and forward navigation arrow since they are separate?

Pls see this link [CLICK HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-bootstrap-carousel-multiple-image-video?file=app%2Fcarousel-basic.html)

**CODE**

```
<div [ngClass]="{'first': myCarousel?.activeId == '0', 'last': myCarousel?.activeId == imageUrls.length - 1}">
    <!-- {{ myCarousel?.activeId }} -->

    <ngb-carousel #myCarousel [showNavigationArrows]="imageUrls.length > 1 || videoUrls.length > 1" [showNavigationIndicators]="false" interval="0">
        <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let url of imageUrls; let i = index" [id]="i">
            <img class="active" [src]="url" />
          </ng-template>
            <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let url of videoUrls; let i2 = index" [id]="i2">
                <video class="active" [src]="url" controls></video>
            </ng-template>
    </ngb-carousel>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this using css

```
:ng-deep .carousel-control-next-icon, .carousel-control-prev-icon {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: I have no problem on the css.  I have already got it. My problem is on hiding on the cursor of video and image together. I got already hiding the cursor but the problem is on these code [ngClass]="{'first': myCarousel?.activeId == '0', 'last': myCarousel?.activeId == imageUrls.length - 1}". You have to tweak this code since it only works on image or video but not both

Answer (score 0):

You can take `max` length among them

In .ts file

```
max(x,y):Number{
    return Math.max(x,y);
}
```

and then

```
[ngClass]="{'first': myCarousel?.activeId == '0', 'last': myCarousel?.activeId == max(imageUrls.length,videoUrls.length)-1}
```

css

```
::ng-deep .first .carousel-control-prev{
    display:none !important;
}
::ng-deep .last .carousel-control-next {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: The image and video is overlapping. Pls check my stackblitz. I have edited it to your answer

Comment: it think its because of same template id try this: `<ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let url of videoUrls; let i2 = index" [id]="i2+imageUrls.length">
    <video class="active" [src]="url" controls></video>
   </ng-template>`

Comment: It still not working. When you add multiple images/video. some images/videos doesnt appear –

Comment: form me that stackblitz example working, i dont see any missing image or video

Comment: The problem now is the prev and forward arrow. First you need to hide the prev navigation arrow when you are on the first slide and Last you need to hide the forward navigation arrow

Comment: try css: `::ng-deep .first .carousel-control-prev{
    display:none !important;
}
::ng-deep .last .carousel-control-next {
    display: none !important;
}`

Comment: This is not the problem on css. This on the logic part